# Java: How to build and use packages from the terminal

Tags: java, package

I've used Eclipse for most of my Java programming, but I'm now volunteering at a prison to teach inmates, and they don't have access to any IDE so we have to do everything from the terminal.  (I'm also primarily a Math teacher but doing what I can for the CompSci stuff.)  As I understand the file structure in Eclipse, when you have a package called, say, `fsk`, you place it in a hierarchy like

```
fsk
    src
        Sort.java
        Main.java
    bin
        Sort.class
        Main.class
```

where the Main class calls on the Sort class, so to compile the source code at the terminal I write

```
$~/fsk/src: javac Sort.java -d ../bin
```

The `Sort.java` file starts with

```
package fsk;
...
```

and the `Main.java` file has the package name and makes a simple call to the `Sort` class

```
package fsk;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> li = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        li.add(1);

        Sort<Integer> s = new Sort<Integer>();
        s.insertionSort(li);
    }
}
```

The `Sort.java` file seems to compile just fine, but when I try to compile the `Main.java` file I get the error that it cannot find the symbol "Sort".

If I do all of this without any package declaration, everything works just fine.  Besides modeling this after how I understood Eclipse to work I have also been using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html and thought I was faithfully reproducing the structure and code, but apparently not.

[Edit: Correction, I have been mostly going off of the Eclipse structure as I understand it, I'm now noticing that when the Oracle tutorial structures this it uses a structure like

```
src
    fsk
        Sort.java
        Main.java
bin 
    fsk
        Sort.class
        Main.class
```

So I suppose my question now is:  am I misunderstanding how Eclipse structures the files, and do I need to instead structure them as in the above?]

Comment: Eclipse uses the same structure.

Answer (score 1):

The structure is fine. You'll want to compile all the Java files with one `javac` invocation.

```
javac fsk/*.java -d ../bin
```

This will get annoying once you start having multiple packages. Long term you should use a build tool such as [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/), or [Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Compiling files by hand gets mighty tiresome.